# Probability of getting heads for a condition of the first flip to be a head?

Tags: probability

If a coin is tossed thrice, what is the probability of getting two or more heads in terms of getting a head at first?
Here 'the first one is head' is not given. It's a condition that if first one is head, then find the probability of getting two or more heads.

Comment: “The first one is a head” is in fact given. That’s what “in terms of getting a head at first” means. Your last sentence is equivalent to this.

Comment: I elaborated it for making it understandable..You can continue with the last sentence if the first one is confusing to you..I want the correct answer of the math if you please..

Comment: What is the _original_ wording of the problem? It seems as if you’re paraphrasing. This is more a question of interpretation of the words than of any mathematics per se. There are key phrases that determine whether or not you’re meant to interpret it as a conditional probability problem.

Comment: Looks like you are a language specialist more than a mathematician. You are wasting my time since two days for finding wording error but didn't give such a damn clue to my question whatever the meaning is. You should better be a language editor in this group.

Comment: If anyone’s wasting anyone’s time it’s you. Choosing the correct solution method depends entirely upon the correct interpretation of the problem statement. With only your two slightly different paraphrasings of it, there’s no way to tell what the correct interpretation should be.

Comment: And I've always seen that, if two different interpretation of a question arise, then mathematicians try to answer the both form of it to make him clear. In this group we ask questions to know from reputed specialists. But 'like you' type guys discourage. And wasting time? If you can't answer you shouldn't reply the 1st one in my question. I've already got my answer by asking the same question from PhD holder mathematicians at quora.com. They aren't language specialist like you. If you aren't capable, then don't spoil anyone's encouragement in this group. It's a helping group where we learn.

Comment: I’m not trying to discourage you. You may have noticed that **no one** besides yourself has answered your question. I’m trying to get you to clarify it so that it _can_ be answered. As it stands, it’s not clear what it is you’re after. If you’re looking for the correct interpretation of some problem you’ve been given, then include that original problem, which for some reason you refuse to do. If the problem statement is indeed ambiguous, leading to the different answer that “some” have given, then that will become clear. All you’ve given anyone to go by is your interpretation of it.

Comment: I could give you the original problem from book. But it is written in Bengali. So if it helps I can upload it.

Comment: In English mathematical writing, there are conventional phrases such as “given that ...” that signal whether a conditional or joint probability is meant. The same occurs in other languages as well. Assuming that the question wasn’t written poorly, which sadly is always a possibility, you should be able to figure out which was meant by comparing this problem to others for which you know or have been given the correct interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

Let, A = ways of having head first {HHH,HHT,HTH,HTT}
 and B = ways of having head first and more heads {HHH,HHT,HTH}
Now probability P(B/A) = P(A∩B)/P(A) = 3/4

To my thoughts, according to conditional probability, the answer is 3/4. But some says it's 3/8. Please enlight me with proper discussion.

N.B: I am not used to type mathematical terms well. Apology for this.

Comment: Who are these “some?”

Comment: "Some" includes some of my year mates and teachers too..